# Jenkinsfile multiline sh continue on error

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to do some Docker cleanup steps before a Jenkins build. This is the build step:

```
steps {
    script {
        try {
            sh '''
                docker container stop  $(docker ps -q)
                docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
                docker  rmi -f $(docker images -q)
                docker build -f Dockerfile_build | tee buildlog.txt
            '''
        } catch(err) {
            echo err.getMessage()
        }
    }
}
```

The first lines of the `sh` part may fail, causing the whole build to fail:

> [Pipeline] sh 
> ++ docker ps -q 
> + docker container stop Error: you must provide at least one name or id
> [Pipeline] echo 
> script returned exit code 125

However, that only means that there's no cleanup to do. I want to continue the build job, no matter how many of the first three lines fail. My question is whether I have to put each of them in its own try/catch block, or if there's a more concise way of saying "try these and ignore any errors".

Comment: check if a docker is running before try to stop them. It is always better than run in an error

Comment: Fine. So what would be the most concise way of doing that then? Checking for a) running containers, b) existing containers and finally c) existing images, each followed by a  rm statement? The desired semantics is "make sure there are no docker images". I actually don't care much about whether there were some, I just want them gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue your script even if you get errors for individual commands you can `set +e` in your script, but the `sh` step will never error out. You can also ignore first 3 commands and then error out the last command as well by setting `-e` and removing it. See the example below.

```
sh '''
  #!/bin/bash
  set +e
  docker container stop  $(docker ps -q)
  docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
  docker  rmi -f $(docker images -q)
  set -e
  docker build -f Dockerfile_build | tee buildlog.txt
'''
```

Comment: Why do we need `set +e` here? This is the default behaviour for bash anyway.

Comment: @user1934428 Good question :) This is something specific to Jenkins. Jenkins will always run shell scripts with `-xe` flags. So that's the default behavior in Jenkins.